# Java for loop with if statement only iterating once

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

I have a version of a login for an employee system i would like to make, I have a for loop which should go through the entire list of Accounts, then see if the name of an employee matches one in the list then the if statement continues, further questions asked etc...  it seems to only iterate once and then stop as it will only find the first user and tell me the other accounts do not exisit, even though they do!! What am i doing wrong? Also my list contains Employees and Managers which inherit from Account, the if statement uses the getName in Account to compare if it equals to the user input. Sorry if this is ridiculously stupid/bad! thanks.

```
List <Account> Accounts = new LinkedList<Account>();
```

Here is where i populate my Account, the main method calls this and the list() is called whihc contains the problematic loop

```
public void add() {
    Employee Geoff = new Employee("Geoff", "password1");
    Manager Bob = new Manager("Bob", "password2");
    Employee John = new Employee("John", "password3");

    Accounts.add(Geoff);
    Accounts.add(Bob);
    Accounts.add(John);
    list();

    }
```

problem:

```
System.out.println("Hello welcome: ");
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
String empName = Scan.nextLine();

for (Account a : Accounts) { 
        System.out.println(a);
        if (a.getname().equals(empName)) {

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter your passcode: ");

            String code = Scan.nextLine();

                if (a.check(code) == true) {
                    System.out.println("logged in");
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Employee does not exist!");
        login();

    }
```

I am doing the print statement in the for loop to see what it is findng, and unfortunalty it is only the first account

EDIT: I have included more code here, my after my initial if statement i want to check if the code the user enters is also correct.

Comment: Perhaps something inside the if-block is causing problems.  Please include that code too.

Comment: Can you show us where you are populating `Accounts` with data?

Comment: Have you tried tracing through the execution in the debugger?

Comment: Please complete it. Post everything until the closing of the for loop. And please indent it properly.

Comment: All the for loop is there

Comment: Once you match the name AND the password is validated, you must **BREAK** out of the loop.  If the current name does not match, you must **CONTINUE** searching until all Account names have been read.  Also, the putting this: `if(a.check(code) == true){...}` is redundant. Simply do `if(a.check(code) ){...}`. Lastly, your `List` data types do not match: `Account` vs. `Employee` and `Manager`.

Comment: Employee and Manager inherit from Account, and I understand what you are saying with the break as i would ideally like a new method to start in its place rather than it, also i assumed since that it firstly could not find the Account then it would carry on searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> see if the name of an employee matches one in the list then the if
>   statement continues, further questions asked etc... it seems to only
>   iterate once and then stop as it will only find the first user and
>   tell me the other accounts do not exisit, even though they do!!

If it works for one employee and tells that others don't exist then your for loop does **not** iterate once.

The output you get is exactly what the code looks like. You get username **once** then try to match the same name with every employee in the list. If the names are equal you ask for password, otherwise you print out that employee doesn't exist. Everything right as it is in the code. You should add to your question the expected behaviour so I, or someone else can fix your code without guessing the purpose of your methods.

Here's one of those guesses:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
String empName = Scan.nextLine();
boolean userFound = false;
for (Account a : Accounts) { 
        System.out.println(a);
        if (a.getname().equals(empName)) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter your passcode: ");
            String code = Scan.nextLine();
                if (a.check(code) == true) {
                    System.out.println("logged in");
                    userFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

if(userFound) {
    login();
} else {
    System.out.println("User not found.");
}
```

Comment: I have a for loop which should go through the entire list of Accounts... That is the intended behaviour, for some reason it is not doing this

Comment: Do you want to log every user in the list or just find one and log him in?  And your loop does it, it goes through every employee in your list. Please include real output of your code. Also, see the code that will get one username from the list.

Comment: find one and log him in, so compare each account in the list until it finds one with that name, the output is this Please enter your name: 
Bob
Employee does not exist!

Comment: that is when i try Bob but for Geoff it allows me to ask for the passcode and log, the only account which the loop so far lets

Comment: @aluckii Then try my code, your code saying Employee does not exist is no news, it will do it no matter what.

Comment: Ah yes it does! I assumed it just wasn't getting past the first iteration and then failing, I wouldn't have thought a boolean would do much but it does! Thank you very much for the help, and sorry for the confusion earlier!

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution that doesn't use your `Account` class (since I do not know what it looks like) and instead uses a Map:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Hello welcome: ");
   System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
   String empName = input.nextLine();
   boolean found = false;

   Map<String, String> accounts = new HashMap<String, String>();
   accounts.put("Geoff", "password1");
   accounts.put("Bob", "password2");
   accounts.put("John", "password3");

   Set<String> names = accounts.keySet();

   for (String a : names)
   {
      if (!a.equals(empName))
      {
         continue;
      }
      found = true;

      // three tries to login
      boolean success = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter your passcode: ");
         String code = input.nextLine();

         if (accounts.get(a).equals(code))
         {
            System.out.println("logged in");
            success = true;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Wrong password... try again");
         }
      }
      if(!success)
      {
         System.out.println("User failed to authenticate after 3 attempts. User has been locked out!");
      }

   }
   if(!found)
   {
      System.out.println("Employee does not exist!");
   }
}
```

Since I do not know what the `login()` method does, I just simply added that into the code. This solution iterates three times in an attempt to get the correct password. If that fails, a message is displayed.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, I only know a little about the use of maps in Java, but this solutions looks great, thank you for your time

Comment: @aluckii, if it satisfies your question, please mark it as such. Also, you can replace the map with your `Account` objects and should work just fine.